# How to Collect first element of each row of type int[][] using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How do I collect `List<Integer>` containing the first element of each row of 2D `int[][]` array.

Please see below sample code

```
int[][] input = new int[][]  { {1,2,3,4,5}, {4,5,6,7,8} };

// Expecting output : List<Integer> -> {1, 4 }

// Trying something like this
List<Integer> output = Arrays.stream(input)
                .collect(r -> r[0]);
```

Comment: title "Collect **every** element" not the same as "containing the **first** element of each row" - What do you really want?

Comment: In fact, it confused me in the first place when reading this.

Comment: Updated the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);`

```
List<Integer> output = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(r->r[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

if you want to use just `collect` ->  `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)` do like this:

```
Arrays.stream(input)
      .collect(ArrayList::new,(l,e)->l.add(e[0]),List::addAll);
```

supplier: `ArrayList::new`

accumulator:`(l,e)->l.add(e[0])`

combiner: `List::addAll`

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int[][] input = new int[][]  { {1,2,3,4,5}, {4,5,6,7,8} };
List<Integer> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();
Arrays.asList(input).forEach(item -> finalResult.add(item[0]));
System.out.println(finalResult);
```